# How can I track my kid's multi-browser website history?

Tags: windows, logging

My kid is 14 years old, homeschooled and capable computer user. All of her school work is done online; the computer literacy course even uses 3 different browsers, Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

I have 2 laptops, running Win7 (one is Pro, the other Home). Is there a way to get all of her browser history in one place? I have to account for 60 minutes of class time per subject per day, but trying to do this across all 3 is getting too complicated.

My kid and I talk about internet safety and usage regularly and she knows that I monitor where she goes and how long she is there. Secrecy is not an issue.

Comment: Not sure I understand the precise problem you are trying to solve... Are you trying to view the histories, or use the logs to try to build profiles of time spent per site?

Comment: It's not a question related to technology but education. No place here for such debate. Ask a psychologist or a pediatrics specialist for this.

Comment: @climenole As it stands, this question is rather technical. The OP even mentioned the social aspects were not that relevant in this case.

Answer (score 4):

One way to collect centralised logs would be to install a [HTTP proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) on one computer and configure all the computers to use that proxy.

You could enforce this with settings at your Internet/broadband router (only allow HTTP from the computer acting as the proxy)

To distinguish between different people's traffic you can configure the proxy to require a login.

I am only familiar with the (free) [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxy server, which provides comprehensive facilities but may not be the easiest to configure. There may be a solution using Microsoft software. Your router may have a proxy capability (or be upgradeable to [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start))

An educational project for your kid might be to [set up squid](http://www.jermsmit.com/?tag=raspberry-pi)  on a [$35 computer](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)

Comment: One detail to check with a proxy-server that is not setup on all mobile devices (the 2 laptops) is the possibility of these laptops being used outside the perimeter of such a centralized proxy and subsequent loss of metering data. Think: college campus and other WiFi hotspots considered friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this?

http://www.manictime.com/

Seems built for business time tracking, but could ba applied to your situation.

"Powerful statistics: 
See which applications you use the most or on which web sites you spend the most time. Also easily figure out how much time you spent working on projects to accurately bill your clients or just keep track of your work."

Found here:

http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-track-the-amount-of-time-I-spend-on-each-website-in-my-browser

Answer (score 1):

The [ManicTime Professional](http://www.manictime.com/BuyNow/) version (presently at $67 for single user) supports

1. share data between ManicTime installations
2. generate reports with TimeSheet

There is a 15 day trial version if you want to check it out first.
I think it can track browser history too -- but, that needs to be verified further.

ps: `BrianAdkins` has referred [this Quora page](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-track-the-amount-of-time-I-spend-on-each-website-in-my-browser) that sounds promising for more information (`+1`)

Comment: how is this answer not just a copy of BrianAdkins answer made 15 minutes before?

Comment: @BonGart BrianAdkins' "answer" had been converted to a comment since it was just a link to the Quora page and *nothing* else. Brian had edited his deleted answer later to include the link to ManicTime. After that, his answer was undeleted. It seems nik wrote this post in the meantime (although he should have been able to see the deleted answer).

Comment: I think when a deleted answer is brought back to life the original time stamp should be changed....would put a stop to this confusion and nonsense.

Comment: My view of the sequence: I did see the deleted answer. But, the negative votes all around made me feel that the question was doomed. I up-voted things and highlighted on the paid-parts of ManicTime which seemed useful to the OP. I have also referred the comment from where I picked up the Quora point. I am independently aware of ManicTime (as you might find from my other answers).

Answer (score 0):

Check the manual for your router/modem that was supplied by the ISP.  Most modern routers have logging built in so that you can see the websites and timestamps that were visited.

Also, products like [Netnanny](http://www.netnanny.com/) and its competitors have the ability to log and limit a users website usage.